# d3 tickFormat error - converting v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to convert d3 from version 3 to version 4 but I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: invalid format: function (d) {
            var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(d);
            return prefix.scale(d) + prefix.symbol;
        }
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width])
    .domain([2000, 2018])
        .domain(d3.extent(countries, function(d) { return d.published_year; }))

//Set new x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return xScale.tickFormat((mobileScreen ? 4 : 8),function(d) {
            var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(d);
            return prefix.scale(d) + prefix.symbol;
        })(d);
    })

    .scale(xScale);
//Append the x-axis
wrapper.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

**Update**:
I wanted to show year on x-axis in v4 d3 and with the help of John I did it in one line:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([2000, 2018])
    .domain(d3.extent(countries, function(d) { return d.published_year; }))

//Set new x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(""))
    .scale(xScale);
```

Comment: With regards to your edit; you might not even need to specify the tick formatter if your years are integer values.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.formatPrefix` is not being called as it should. It is expecting a specifier string which determines the SI prefix.

https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_formatPrefix